# Ionic 2 Modal parameters

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, binding, ionic2, modal-dialog

I want to show a modal in Ionic 2 and pass some parameters through. That works fine.
My main problem: Are the parameters bind to the navParams?
The main problem is, that the parameters are bind to the navParams?

```
var dataToPass = this.VLSMfields;
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(VlsmMetaDataPage,dataToPass);
modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
  //this.VLSMfields is already edited <- Problem
  if(data != null){
      this.VLSMfields.Inputs = data;
  }
 });
modal.present();
```

The Modal:

```
    export class VlsmMetaDataPage {

  constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController,public alertCtrl: AlertController,  public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  Hosts = {
    avalible : 0,
    used : 0,
    left:0,
  }
  inputs = [];
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad VlsmMetaDataPage');
     this.Hosts.avalible = this.navParams.data.Hosts;
     this.Hosts.left = this.navParams.data.Hosts;
     this.inputs = this.navParams.data.Inputs;
  }
  closeModal(){
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(null);
  }
  submitModal(){
//Gets edited before in HTML
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss(this.inputs);
  }
}
```

What's wrong? 
I Just want to set "this.VLSMfields.Inputs" to data if dismiss is not null.

Edit:
I hope this code explains my problem better:

```
export class ProfilePage {
  private test;
  private test2;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public viewCtrl: ViewController, private navParams: NavParams) {
    this.test = navParams.get("data");
    this.test2 = navParams.get("data");
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ProfilePage');
  }
  private doSmth(){
    this.test.Edit = "test123";
    console.log(this.test); // {edit:"test123"}
    console.log(this.test2);// {edit:"test123"}
  }
  private cancel(){
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }
  private submit(){
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }

}
```

Why has "test2" the same value as "test"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,...

Just, use `JSON.stringify(this.object)` to remove the strange binding.
To get an Object from the string use `JSON.parse(this.objectJson);`

I hope this helps others with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your data to the modal using an object like this:

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(VlsmMetaDataPage, { data: dataToPass });
```

And then you can get it in your modal like this:

```
public params;
constructor(navParams: NavParams) {
  this.params = navParams.get('data');
}
```

You are accessing the NavParams instance directly via the `data` property and because NavParams is an injectable you are modifying the data directly if you do not use the `get()` method. You can find the NavParams docs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavParams/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This didn't work for me. Same behavior, the dataToPass changes to the value of "this.params".

Comment: Yes because it is assigned in the constructor?

Comment: Maybe it helps me to explain me the problem I described in the Edit? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this for assigning the navParams to local variables: `this.test = Object.assign({}, navParams.get('data'));`